# Pushpin click event

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps, pushpin

I have a cluster of pushpins and i have added the click events for all the pushpins in foreach. now i need to find out which pushpin is clicked so as to do the actions accordingly. Below is my sample code.

```
 private void setpins()
 {
            Pushpin pin = null;    

            lstpin.Add(new clsPushpin() { stores = "chennai", _loc= new locations() { lat = 13.04, longd = 80.17 } });
            lstpin.Add(new clsPushpin() { stores = "Karur", _loc = new locations() { lat = 10.58, longd = 78.07 } });
            lstpin.Add(new clsPushpin() { stores = "coimbatore", _loc = new locations() { lat = 11.00, longd = 77.00 } });

            foreach (clsPushpin cls in lstpin)
            {
                pin = new Pushpin();
                GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(cls._loc.lat, cls._loc.longd);
                pin.Location = geo;
                pin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A = 255, R = 0, G = 100, B = 120 });
                pin.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                mymap.Children.Add(pin);
                pin.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pushpintap);
            }
            mymap.Center = pin.Location;
            mymap.SetView(pin.Location, 5.0);
  }

  private void pushpintap(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    
  {
      //Messagebox are what ever    
      MessageBox.Show("My lat long is:"+lat,+long);    
  }
```

With the above snippet,the last pushpin's value is saved. But i wanna find the exact pin which gets selected to notify/pop up accoringly. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

Store the clsPushpin object in the Pushpin Tag property.

In the pushpin click event cast the sender.tag as a clsPushpin object to get the data for that pushpin.

```
        foreach (clsPushpin cls in lstpin)
        {
            pin = new Pushpin();
            GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(cls._loc.lat, cls._loc.longd);
            pin.Location = geo;
            pin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A = 255, R = 0, G = 100, B = 120 });
            pin.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            mymap.Children.Add(pin);
            pin.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pushpintap);
            pin.Tag = cls;
        }
```

Then in your pushpintap event handler do this:

```
  private void pushpintap(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    
  {
  //Messagebox are what ever    
    clsPushpin cls = sender.tag as clsPushpin;

    MessageBox.Show("My lat long is:"+cls.lat.ToString()+","+cls.long.ToString());    
  }
```

You probably should be using databinding to bind the data to a collection of pushpins.

Answer (score 1):

You should query the `sender` in the `pushpintap` event to find out the details of the pin that was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and looking for a solution I found your question. What I did was to define a method that created a `MouseButtonEventHandler` dynamically. For example if you want to show information about each `cls` object you can define the next method:

```
    public MouseButtonEventHandler getHandler(clsPushpin cls)
    {
        return delegate(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cls.stores+" at "+cls._loc.lat+","+cls._loc.longd);
            };
    }
```

and call it each time you create/add a `Pushpin`:

```
pin.MouseLeftButtonUp += getHandler(cls);
```

[I tried doing it directly without defining the `getHandler` method (that is: `pin.MouseLeftButtonUp += delegate(...`) and it didn't work]